# Been assigned to make a custom robot able to navigate and on it's own

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As my final year project, I've been assigned to make an NUC robot based ROS robot to self navigate. My previous seniors manage to get the movement and camera nodes to work. Using teleop and rviz. Honestly I don't know where to start in terms of self navigation and mapping. Any help would be amazing thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251687/been-assigned-to-make-a-custom-robot-able-to-navigate-and-on-it%27s-own/) by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

A good starting point is the documentation of the navigation stack: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation

Check section 3 for how to [setup the navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) and [how to build a map](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/MapBuilding)

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1